# How to show $\lceil ( \sqrt3 +1)^{2n}\rceil$ where $n \in \mathbb{ N}$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

> Show that $ \left\lceil( \sqrt3 +1)^{2n}\right\rceil$ where $n \in  \mathbb{N}$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$.

---

I wrote the binomial expansion of $ ( \sqrt3 +1)^{2n}$ and  $( \sqrt3 -1)^{2n}$ and then added them to confirm that the next integer is even. 
Afterwards I applied $AM \ge GM$ on the two terms to get $ ( \sqrt3 +1)^{2n} + ( \sqrt3 -1)^{2n} \ge (2^{n+1})$.

Now I'm unable to figure out the next step. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: No induction pls

Comment: A good start, but why the wish to avoid induction? To me it feels like the most natural approach. I would do a two step induction based on the recurrence relation.

Comment: OK, no induction, then no solution.

Comment: Ah.. I found this question in an objective paper with RHS as one of the options. This makes me feel that there might be a better method of solving this question. :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is there really no other method of solving?

Comment: Pls don't close this question, I am searching for an answer I'll put it here if I get.

Comment: The natural way is to find a recurrence, and then induction is inevitable. There are actually not many number-theoretic results that can be proved without induction, or by calling on results that do use induction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$(\sqrt{3}\pm 1)^2=(4 \pm 2\sqrt{3})=2(2 \pm \sqrt{3})$$

Therefore
$$( \sqrt3 +1)^{2n} + ( \sqrt3 -1)^{2n} =2^n \left[(2 + \sqrt{3})^n+(2 - \sqrt{3})^n \right] $$

Now, use the Binomial Theorem to prove that $(2 + \sqrt{3})^n+(2 - \sqrt{3})^n $ is an even integer.

Answer (score 1):

Let:
$$ A_n = (\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}+(\sqrt{3}-1)^{2n} = (4+2\sqrt{3})^n+(4-2\sqrt{3})^{n}.\tag{1} $$
Since $0<4-2\sqrt{3}<\frac{2}{3}$, we have that $A_n$ is the integer giving the ceiling of $(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}$.

Now we have: 
$$ A_0 = 2, \quad A_1 = 8,\qquad A_{n+2} = 8 A_{n+1} - 4 A_{n}\tag{2} $$
and if we take:
$$ \nu_2(n) = \max\{m\in\mathbb{N}: 2^m\mid n\} \tag{3}$$
it happens that:
$$ \nu_2(A_n)\geq n+1\tag{4} $$
can be proved by induction from $(2)$. We can also factor a $2^n$ from the RHS of $(1)$ then just study the parity of the sequence given by:
$$ B_n = (2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n,\tag{5}$$
for which:
$$ B_0=2,\quad B_1=4,\quad B_2=14,\quad B_{n+2}=4B_{n+1}-B_n\equiv -B_n\pmod{4}.\tag{6}$$
That gives:

> $$ \nu_2(A_n) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}n+1 & \text{if }n\text{ is odd,}\\n+2 &\text{if }n\text{ is even.}\end{array}\right.\tag{7}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}=I+f$ where $I$ is the integeral part of $R$ and $f$ is the fractional part of $R$.
Let $r=(\sqrt{3}-1)^{2n}$
Now, we know that $r<1$ as $\sqrt{3}-1$ is less than $1$ and $n\geq 1$. Also,
$R+r=2({2n\choose0}\sqrt{3}^{0}+{2n\choose2}\sqrt{3}^{2}+\ldots+{2n\choose2n}\sqrt{3}^{2n})=2k$ where $k$ is a positive integer. Since, $r$ was less than $1$, this implies that $r+f=1$ and $I=2k-1$.
This means that $I$ is odd so $I+1$ is even.
**EDIT:** I am not deleting this answer so others can see how OP reached at the conclusion that $\lceil (\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}\rceil$ is even.

Comment: I think the question was about the next *larger* integer (rounded up).

Comment: But the greatest integer function returns the rounded down value for positive numbers. OP asked to show that the greatest integer of $(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}$ is divisble by $2^{n+1}$, which is false.

Comment: You calculated  $\lfloor x \rfloor$, but $\lceil x \rceil$ denotes the smallest integer *larger* than $x$, e.g. $\lceil 2.1 \rceil = 3$. Originally the question explicitly asked about *"the integer immediately greater than ..."*. This was then changed to use the symbolic notation $\lceil \ldots \rceil$.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought he wrote the greatest integer function $[x]$